# Netbeans and Maven, how to stop maven from attempting downloads?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to build an existing project using Netbeans.  The IDE and plugins have been installed on a system which does not and cannot have internet access.

When I try to build a simple project in the IDE Mavan tries to connect to the internet to download "exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom" and because this fails the entire build process fails.

At present I have create a very simple application that has a single line:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Simon!");
    }
```

Comment: In this case, maybe you don't need to have a maven project. Try using a "regular" java project. However, if you do need to have a maven project (which helps you a lot managing the dependencies), you will need to have an accessible software repository (from your computer) containing all the dependency.

Comment: I have a project, in that I'm tasked with opening and assessing an existing Maven Project, but the system that I have to use cannot have internet access for security reasons, is there anyway to disable or stop Maven from trying to access the internet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use -o switch to run maven in offline mod. This way maven will only look for local m2 folder. ( I assume you have all your dependencies and plugins your project needs in the m2 folder.) example command `mvn -o package`

If You want to use it from netbeans You have to create custom actions. Following link explains how it can be done. You should select `Clean and Build project` for `Actions` and add `-o` to start of `Execute Goals` section.

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/configuring-running-specific-methods-in-maven-projects-in-netbeans-ide

As a side note: If You are going develop an application within a team this way I suggest setting up an internal repository manager. There are multiple free alternatives for this like Artifactory and Sonatype Nexus.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

Comment: Thank you, I've found a bunch of dependences that are required for the project which I also need to obtain in order to build the project.

Comment: @SPlatten The link in the answer shows how to create and execute custom goals. ( I dont have netbeans installed so I cannot test this)

Comment: The version of NetBeans I have 8.0.2 doesn't have any "Actions" node in the Project Properties...I have requested the current version of NetBeans to be installed.

Comment: @SPlatten I am not familiar with netbeans. You can use maven command line to build your project If custom actions cannot be created. https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-commandline.html

Answer (score -1):

Please note that buildling with Maven "without Internet" is non-trivial. We did it the following way:

- Set up a Nexus that is connected to the internet and build a project against it. To get fixed versions of the plugins, we set up a parent pom to be used by every maven project.
- Copy the cached artifacts from the online Nexus to an offline instance of Nexus. Now you can connect your Maven against this offline Nexus and you can build your project. Make sure that you use the parent pom again so that all plugin versions are fixed.

Note that if you "just build the project offline" the build will fail because "plugin XY is missing". When you download this plugin and install it to your local repository or offline Nexus, surely the next plugin will be missing. And so on. And so on. Even the smallest Maven project without any real Java code needs 100+ files from MavenCentral to run properly.